# Assigning itemsource to private property of listview not working please guide

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
<ListView x:Name="listview"ItemsSource="{Binding NewDeviceSessionList}"SelectedItem="{Binding DeviceSession, Mode=TwoWay}">

private List newDeviceSessionlist;

public List<DeviceSession> NewDeviceSessionList
{
    get => newDeviceSessionlist;
    set => SetProperty(ref newDeviceSessionlist, value);
}
```

//Not working
newDeviceSessionlist=listsource

//Working
NewDeviceSessionList=listsource`

Comment: updating the private backing store won't (and shouldn't) work.  Why do you expect it to?  Why can't you just do it the correct way, by assigning the public property?

Comment: Please set the property to public, if you set it private,Object and UI Control can not bind successfully, UI control cannot access the object ,TwoWay binding  are not synchronized.